# Query Between two date

Tags: php, mysql, date

```
SELECT product.pname,stock.pid,stock.qty,stock.rate
FROM product,stock
WHERE (date BETWEEN '2012-04-10' AND '2012-07-16') AND product.pid=stock.pid
```

This is my sql query but problem is when execute this query its show single result means my product table contains pid and pname and stock table contains pid,rate,qty and date.

I want to display record between two dates.
My query match with two records. But when i add "AND product.pid=stock.pid" its show only 1 record.
I want to display the product name from product table in the respect of pid of stock table.

Comment: Left join? SELECT product.pname,stock.pid,stock.qty,stock.rate FROM product LEFT JOIN stock ON product.pid=stock.pid WHERE (date BETWEEN '2012-04-10' AND '2012-07-16') AND product.pid=stock.pid

Comment: Write your textual description better.

Answer (score 0):

Probably some product is not in the stock. Also I recommend you to do a JOIN like this:

```
SELECT product.pname,stock.pid,stock.qty,stock.rate
FROM product
LEFT JOIN
stock
ON product.pid=stock.pid
WHERE (date BETWEEN '2012-04-10' AND '2012-07-16')
```

I used LEFT JOIN that means to return products no matter if have or nor stock, I think that with this query you will get two Rows.

Comment: To Daniel Aranga: I think you will find that WHERE clause will still make it an equivalent of RIGHT JOIN

Answer (score 0):

First try to get it working without the join:

```
SELECT stock.pid, stock.qty, stock.rate
FROM stock
WHERE stock.date BETWEEN '2012-04-10' AND '2012-07-16'
```

If that works, then use an outer to join to add information to each row without removing any rows.

```
SELECT product.pname, stock.pid, stock.qty, stock.rate
FROM stock
LEFT JOIN product ON product.pid=stock.pid
WHERE stock.date BETWEEN '2012-04-10' AND '2012-07-16'
```

The product name will be NULL if no product is found.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below query.

```
SELECT product.pname,stock.pid,stock.qty,stock.rate
FROM product,stock
WHERE stock.date BETWEEN '2012-04-10' AND '2012-07-16' AND product.pid=stock.pid
```

Answer (score 0):

Your selection criteria 
WHERE ([stock.]date BETWEEN '2012-04-10' AND '2012-07-16')
makes it effectively RIGHT JOIN, only records that have/had stock within date range will be displayed. If you want to display ALL products irrespective of stock than you will need to add OR [stock.]date IS NULL to your selection criteria.